# document.execCommand Copy All But One Part

Tags: javascript, html

I am generating multiple divs with different information inside each one and I'm trying to have a button that will copy the contents of the div.

The code below will copy everything in the div including the text of the button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function copyText(event) {
    try {
        var element = event.parentNode;
        if (document.body.createTextRange) { // ie
            var range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(element);
            range.select();
            document.execCommand("Copy");
            //setInterval(function () { selection.removeAllRanges(); }, 1000);
            alert('Copied successfully');
        } else if (window.getSelection) { // moz, opera, webkit
            var selection = window.getSelection();
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(element);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
            document.execCommand("Copy");
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            //setInterval(function () { selection.removeAllRanges(); }, 1000);
            alert('Copied successfully');
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert('Not copied successfully - ' + e.message);
    }
}
</script>



<div class="divCard">
    Value1: <%=result("Value1")%><br /><br />
    Value2: <%=result("Value2")%><br /><br />
    <input type="button" id="btnCopytext" onclick="copyText(this)" value="Copy Text" />
</div>
```

Current output:

> ```
> Val1 
> Val2 
> Copy Text
> ```

Desired output:

> ```
> Val1 
> Val2
> ```

How can I copy everything except the btn text?

Also, is there a way to trim the spaces at the end of what was copied?

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping the content you want to copy in an id and passing that element to copy?

```
<div class="divCard">
    <div id='copythis'>
        Value1: <%=result("Value1")%><br /><br />
        Value2: <%=result("Value2")%><br /><br />
    </div>

    <input type="button" id="btnCopytext" value="Copy Text" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
function copyText(event) {
    try {
        var element = document.getElementById("copythis");
        if (document.body.createTextRange) { // ie
            var range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(element);
            range.select();
            document.execCommand("Copy");
            alert('Copied successfully');
        } else if (window.getSelection) { // moz, opera, webkit
            var selection = window.getSelection();
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(element);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
            document.execCommand("Copy");
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            alert('Copied successfully');
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert('Not copied successfully - ' + e.message);
    }
}

document.getElementById("btnCopytext").addEventListener("click",copyText)
```